# unable to load captcha.jsp in my img tag for my registration form

Tags: jsp, captcha, struts1

I am implementing captcha for my my registration form. When my page loads, i do not know why my captcha does not loads(shows).

I am showing my captch using img tag:->   `<img src="captcha.jsp"/>`.
But same captcha when i acceess it through facebox then it is appearing. I do know why it is happening like this.

Please help me if you can.

-Thanks

### index.jsp

```
 <html:form action="/addUserAction?method=addUser" method="post" onsubmit="return validateAddUserForm(this);">
        <html:javascript formName="addUserForm"></html:javascript>
        <table border="0" width="100%" align="center" height="100%">


            <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#d0d67f" colspan="2" ><font size="5" face="Broadway" color="#4d4207">Registration Form</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><div id="ashutosh" style="background:#ffebe8;border:0px solid #dd3c10;background-position: top"> </div> <div id="ansuman"  > </div>   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><img alt=""  src="images/validation/backRequiredGray.gif"><font size="3" face="Broadway" color="#4d4207">Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                <td><html:text tabindex="3" style="height:27px;font-size:16pt;"  property="name" maxlength="240"></html:text></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><img alt=""  src="images/validation/backRequiredGray.gif"><font size="3" face="Broadway" color="#4d4207">Email&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                <td>
                    <html:text tabindex="4" style="height:27px;font-size:16pt;" onkeyup="getEmailCheckResult(this.value);"   property="email"></html:text>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><font size="3" face="Broadway" color="#4d4207">Phone Number&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                <td><html:text tabindex="5" style="height:27px;font-size:16pt;" maxlength="15"  onkeypress="return ValidateNum(this,event)" property="contactNumber"></html:text></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td height="30" align="right" ><font size="3" face="Broadway" color="#4d4207">Code&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                <td height="30" align="left"><img alt=""  src="captcha.jsp" width="208"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td height="30" align="right" valign=""><img src="images/validation/backRequiredGray.gif"><font size="3" face="Broadway" color="#4d4207">Enter Code&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                <td height="30" align="left" >
                    <html:text tabindex="7" property="code"  style="height:27px;font-size:16pt;"  onkeyup="getCapchaCheckResult(this.value);"   size="16" maxlength="13"></html:text>
                 <div id="ansuman"> </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle" colspan="2"><img alt=""  ><font color="#4d4207">By clicking Sign Up, you agree and understand  our</font> <a href="tc.do" target="blank"><font color="#4d4207">Terms & Conditions.</font></a> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td height="30" align="right" valign="middle" colspan="2"><img src="images/validation/backRequiredGray.gif"> Fields Required</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" ><input type="submit" style="height:37px;font-size:16pt;color:#4d4207;" value="Sign Up"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle" colspan="2" bgcolor="#d0d67f"><font color="#4d4207">Please Note: The Password will be emailed to the mail Id provided.</font> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </html:form>
```

### captcha.jsp

```
<%--
        Document   : captcha
        Created on : 23 Jan, 2012, 2:23:50 PM
        Author     : Ashutosh
    --%>


    <%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*,java.awt.*,java.awt.image.*,javax.imageio.*,java.awt.geom.*"%>
    <%
     response.setContentType("image/jpg");
      /* Define number characters contains the captcha image, declare global */
      int iTotalChars= 6;

      /* Size image iHeight and iWidth, declare globl */
      int iHeight=40;
      int iWidth=150;

      /* font style */
      Font fntStyle1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30);
      Font fntStyle2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);

      /* Possible random characters in the image */
      Random randChars = new Random();
      String sImageCode = (Long.toString(Math.abs(randChars.nextLong()), 36)).substring(0,iTotalChars);

      /* BufferedImage is used to create a create new image*/
      /* TYPE_INT_RGB - does not support transpatency, TYPE_INT_ARGB - support transpatency*/
      BufferedImage biImage = new BufferedImage(iWidth, iHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      Graphics2D g2dImage = (Graphics2D) biImage.getGraphics();

      // Draw background rectangle and noisey filled round rectangles
      int iCircle = 15;
      //g2dImage.fillRect(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
      for ( int i = 0; i < iCircle; i++ )
      {
        g2dImage.setColor(new Color(randChars.nextInt(255),randChars.nextInt(255),randChars.nextInt(255)));
        int iRadius = (int) (Math.random() * iHeight / 2.0);
        int iX = (int) (Math.random() * iWidth - iRadius);
        int iY = (int) (Math.random() * iHeight - iRadius);
        //g2dImage.fillRoundRect(iX, iY, iRadius * 2, iRadius * 2,100,100);
      }
      g2dImage.setFont(fntStyle1);
      for ( int i = 0; i < iTotalChars; i++ )
      {
        g2dImage.setColor(new Color(randChars.nextInt(255),randChars.nextInt(255),randChars.nextInt(255)));
        if (i%2==0)
          g2dImage.drawString(sImageCode.substring(i,i+1),25*i,24);
        else
          g2dImage.drawString(sImageCode.substring(i,i+1),25*i,35);
      }

      /* create jpeg image and display on the screen*/
      OutputStream osImage = response.getOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(biImage, "jpeg", osImage);
      //osImage.close();

      /* Dispose function is used destory an image object */
      g2dImage.dispose();

      session.setAttribute("dns_security_code", sImageCode);
      //System.out.println("Captcha Page :"+session.getAttribute("dns_security_code"));


    %>
```

Comment: If you're already using Struts, why not implement your captcha generation as a servlet? This would make debugging _much_ easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your jsp into a servlet!

A jsp is a good choice to create markup files, which don't break if you add unnecessary 
 whitespace inside your file.

Your captcha code works without any change inside a servlet's doGet(...) method.

```
package test.captcha;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class CaptchaServlet extends HttpServlet {

 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    /*
     * Define number characters contains the captcha image, declare global
     */
    int iTotalChars = 6;

    /*
     * Size image iHeight and iWidth, declare globl
     */
    int iHeight = 40;
    int iWidth = 150;

    /*
     * font style
     */
    Font fntStyle1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30);
    Font fntStyle2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);

    /*
     * Possible random characters in the image
     */
    Random randChars = new Random();
    String sImageCode = (Long.toString(Math.abs(randChars.nextLong()), 36)).substring(0, iTotalChars);

    /*
     * BufferedImage is used to create a create new image
     */
    /*
     * TYPE_INT_RGB - does not support transpatency, TYPE_INT_ARGB - support transpatency
     */
    BufferedImage biImage = new BufferedImage(iWidth, iHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2dImage = (Graphics2D) biImage.getGraphics();

    // Draw background rectangle and noisey filled round rectangles
    int iCircle = 15;
    //g2dImage.fillRect(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
    for (int i = 0; i < iCircle; i++) {
        g2dImage.setColor(new Color(randChars.nextInt(255), randChars.nextInt(255), randChars.nextInt(255)));
        int iRadius = (int) (Math.random() * iHeight / 2.0);
        int iX = (int) (Math.random() * iWidth - iRadius);
        int iY = (int) (Math.random() * iHeight - iRadius);
        //g2dImage.fillRoundRect(iX, iY, iRadius * 2, iRadius * 2,100,100);
    }
    g2dImage.setFont(fntStyle1);
    for (int i = 0; i < iTotalChars; i++) {
        g2dImage.setColor(new Color(randChars.nextInt(255), randChars.nextInt(255), randChars.nextInt(255)));
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            g2dImage.drawString(sImageCode.substring(i, i + 1), 25 * i, 24);
        } else {
            g2dImage.drawString(sImageCode.substring(i, i + 1), 25 * i, 35);
        }
    }

    /*
     * create jpeg image and display on the screen
     */
    OutputStream osImage = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(biImage, "jpeg", osImage);
    //osImage.close();

    /*
     * Dispose function is used destory an image object
     */
    g2dImage.dispose();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("dns_security_code", sImageCode);
    //System.out.println("Captcha Page :"+session.getAttribute("dns_security_code"));

}



protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


}
```

create if not exist a web application descriptor:
/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CaptchaServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.captcha.CaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CaptchaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/captcha-image.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This is working fine. And my above code is also working fine when i upload it to server. It was showing error in my localhost server.

Comment: Depending on how your web servlet container is configured you will get some unintended blanks in your JSP, as long as you are generating some kind of markup (html,xml, ...) this is no problem. but for generating binary content JSPs are not a perfect choice, because a single unintended blank inside of a binary file can render it useless.